# Fast way to add a column to a dataframe based on values in one column and bounding values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am trying to do something like this. I have a df, df_A with one column, "cycle", of monotonically increasing values. I have another df, df_B with 2 columns, "cycle_bound" and "name". What I want to do is create a column in df_A, "name" such that for all values of cycle < cycle_bound (and greater than the previous cycle_bound), "name" in df_A is filled with "name" from df_B. An example below, please excuse syntax, not sure how to represent that in text

```
df_A['cycle'] = {0,2,3,6,8,10,35,36}
df_B['cycle_bound','name'] = {(3,one),(11,two),(40,three)}
```

I want to create

```
df_A['cycle','name'] = {(0,one),(2,one),(3,two),(6,two),(8,two),(10,two),(35,three),(36,three)}
```

I have done this using apply/lambda approach and calling a function that uses iterrows() over df_B, but it is still fairly slow. My df_A has about a million rows and df_B has about ten. I am trying to see if there is a faster approach, maybe a vectorization / numpy approach, but couldn't find anything online specific to this case or maybe I am unable to search well enough.

My code looks something like this right now (I added a lower bound column first for ease in df_B):

```
df_A['Name'] = df_A.apply(lambda x: findName(x['cycle']), axis=1)

def findName(cycle):
  for index, l_row in df_B.iterrows():
    if cycle >= l_row['cycle_lowerbound'] and cycle < l_row['cycle_upperbound']:
      return l_row['Name']
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the `name` column to be filled with if the conditions are not met? `NaN`?

Comment: Hi @AJH, I didn't think of that scenario - I suppose you mean if there are entries in the first dataframe higher than the last entry in the second one. I am actually guaranteeing in the context of my use that that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You want an [`asof` merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=merge_asof#pandas.merge_asof).

Specifically make sure to set the direction to 'forward' so that it merges between the correct bounds and I explicitly set `allow_exact_matches=False` to enforce the <, not <=, at the upper bound.

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.DataFrame({'cycle': [0,2,3,6,8,10,35,36]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'cycle_bound': [3, 11, 40],
                     'cycle_name': ['one', 'two', 'three']})

pd.merge_asof(df_A, df_B, 
              left_on='cycle', right_on='cycle_bound',
              direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=False)

   cycle  cycle_bound cycle_name
0      0            3        one
1      2            3        one
2      3           11        two
3      6           11        two
4      8           11        two
5     10           11        two
6     35           40      three
7     36           40      three
```